# JavaScript associative array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

'i have JavaScript associative array name 'options'

```
<script>
options[dynamickey] = Number; 
</script>
```

and i just want to send this array to codeigniter model using jQuery post

```
<script>
$.('link',options);
</script>
```

But the problem is I don't know how to extract each of the keys and values of this array (options). 
My JavaScript array with data looks like this

```
 <script>
  options { 
     id => 135,
     'Chestnut' => 11,
     'Cinamon' => 1
   }
</script>
```

in codeigniter (PHP) model i just wanna extract this array like this

```
<?php
 $id = $this->input->post('id');
//below variable names and data should be dynamic from that javascript array
$chesnut= $this->input->post('dynamic value');
?>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: how can you post to your model!! You need a controller method to handle this

Comment: Yes i have controller but in my post i just ignore that step

Comment: Be aware, [JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/). You have a JavaScript object with properties. This will become important if you ever try to loop over the items or json encode the 'array' as depending on how you create it, it might fail or have extra mystery values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your jQuery, you do a post:

```
var options = { 
    'id' : 135,
    'Chestnut' : 11,
    'Cinamon' : 1
}

$.post('example.com/index.php/firstsegment/secondsegment',options,function(data){...});
```

In a CodeIgniter Controller that receives this post:

```
public firstsegment extends CI_Controller {

    public function secondsegment(){
        $data = $this->input->post();

        if($data){
            /*
            $data will contain this:
            $data = array(
                'id' => '135',
                'Chestnit' => '11',
                'Cinamon' => '1'
            );
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda rare request to be frank. You want something that's probably rendered by your system, to be sent to your system?

Nonetheless. Add a `{ data : options }` along with existing common values in [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

**Example:**

```
var options = { 
    'id' : 135,
    'Chestnut' : 11,
    'Cinamon' : 1
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: options
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```